# Converting IRestResponse to "image/jpg" File

Tags: c#, bitmap, asp.net-core, rest-client

I'm trying to pull an image from an API and return to the DOM through the `File()` method.

Here's what I have so far..

`HomeController.cs`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ImageFromPath()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://{{MYIPADDRESS}}/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel0=");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("postman-token", "random-postman-token");
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Digest username=\"MYUSERNAME\", realm=\"MYENCRYPTEDPASS\", nonce=\"LONGSTRING\", uri=\"/cgi-bin/snapshot.cgi?channel0\", response=\"RESPONSESTRING\", opaque=\"\"");
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);(response.RawBytes);

        return File(response, "image/jpg");
    }
}
```

The only problem here, is that the error on the return statement, `response` shows

> cannot convert from 'RestSharp.IRestResponse' to 'byte[]'

---

When I was pulling the image from the local file system, it was easier and worked, here was my working code for `HomeController.cs`

```
public ActionResult ImageFromPath(string path)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(path))
    {
        var height = bitmap.Size.Height;
        var width = bitmap.Size.Width;

        bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    ms.Position = 0;
    return File(ms, "image/jpg");
}
```

Here's how I was pulling it in my front end (`Index.cshtml`):

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ImageFromPath", new { path = Request.MapPath("~/img/1.jpg") })" />
```

Comment: This line looks off to me... `IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);(response.Content);`

Comment: Also, you likely want `.RawBytes` instead of `.Content`

Comment: @maccettura yes, but the main problem I'm having is how to return everything. Trying to return as a File gives me problems. At least, currently.

Comment: Right, because `File()` takes a `byte[]`.  You are passing it a `IRestResponse`.  If you change your code to: `return File(response.RawBytes, "image/jpg");` you should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line here:

```
return File(response, "image/jpg");
```

You are passing it `response` which is of type `IRestResponse` (a type from RestSharp).

Why would the built in MVC File method know of RestSharp?  `File()` [takes a byte array and a string MIME type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx).

Try:

```
return File(response.RawBytes, "image/jpg");
```

`RawBytes` is a byte array of the raw response from your HTTP Request.  If your API is returning a byte array of an image, this is what you need to pass to your file method.

Comment: Excellent catch! Thanks for your help :)